# Ram Memory for Desktop specifications

Tags: windows-7, memory, bios, motherboard

Yesterday I bought some RAM memory online to upgrade my MSI h55-GD65 mainboard as I'm still running on 2x2GB of RAM at the moment.

I bought 2x kingston-hyperx-fury-4-gb-dimm-ddr3-1333 
This has product code/number: HX313C9FW/4.

I have 4 DIMM slots which can run in dual channel mode.
Bios is set to auto assign voltages and speed.
I also upgraded my BIOS to the latest version but the RAM still doesn't work in my system.

I added the new RAMS in slot 2 and 4 of the mobo (with the old RAMS still in slots 1 and 3 as original), but then my system keeps rebooting, even when I enter BIOS, no beep nothing, just powering off and rebooting himself. The RAMS do get recognized in the BIOS, but before I can do anything it powers off and reboots.

I added the new RAMS seperatly as well (without the old RAMS), but then I get a blue screen when starting up Windows 7 (at this point I can enter BIOS and the BIOS recognizes the RAMS). If I add them both (without the old RAMS) to slots 1 and 3, then my pc doesn't boot and all I get is a black screen.

I am wondering if anyone has a solution to this, or can help me out on which requirements I have forgotten to pay attention to when buying these RAMS. Is this really a compatibility issue or am I missing something?
I also noticed that RAMS do state to be single channel, but when I read the info it was written like 2x single channel makes a dual channel... or is this incorrect?

***EDIT*** ***(answer to the question/guidelines of Przemon)***:
So, I take my old rams out and: 
- when I add the new rams to slot 2 and 4, pc hangs at startup screen/logo before the beeps.
- when I add the new rams to slot 1 and 3 I get no startup screen no nothing, pc runs but does nothing.
- then I pulled out ram in slot 3. BIOS 1 beep, ram recognized, starts up but blue screen on windows startup. Also when I try to enter in safe mode.

I put my old rams back in slots 1 and 3. PC boots fine.
I replaced slot 3 by new RAM and pc runs, but I get no startup screen, no beeps,  nothing.

[screendump of memtest just before system reboots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD3kP.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

Pull out the OLD Ram from the computer, insert new RAM for example to slot 2 and 4 but if it's working on dual Chanel you need insert ram to slots which have the same color for example: slot 1 is: red slot 2: blue slot 3: red slot 4: blue. insert RAM to 1 and 3 or 2 and 4. Now try power on your PC if still cant run, pull out one from RAM for example from slot 3 ( If you have 1-3 combination )
And now try run you PC, if still not work try insert OLD RAM again. If computer starting again pull out one from OLD Ram and Insert ONE OLD ONE NEW Ram. After all this steps plese tell me what happened.

Comment: Then I sort of get the result as stated in my post. But if I then just put back my old rams in, the system will only boot fine after 5-6 times, the first few times it reboots or hangs too... I always get a black screen, or system reboot or blue screen when windows 7 starts up with the different combinations.

Comment: In BIOS , do you see 12GB ram ? If you insert all of your memory... and i Try help... getting -1 ... good...

Tell me, can you go to the safe mode ? Pressing f8 ?. You can check your RAM using memtest86+

Comment: not my -1. Yes i see the 12GB of ram. I did exactly as you asked and will expand my question with the results.

Comment: Ohhh By chance, I removed me cooments. I writing again. You can make bootable pendrive witch memtest86+ insert your new ram and test it. Maybe your ram is relay broken :/

Comment: System always reboots at 55% of the memtest86+. Strange thing, cause when I do not run the test the system doesn't reboot in this configuration (1 new ram in slot 1), so I assume it is the test that fails somewhere, no?

Comment: What do you mean ?"system doesn't reboot in this configuration (1 new ram in slot 1)".  Are you mean : System doesn't  reboot and worked normal or only start but you see "Starting windows" and nothing more or blue/black screen.
Hmm it is interesting situation. For better diagnostic let’s face it RAM  which you have inside slot now i name RAM "A" three Others B - another new ram. C and D will be a 2 old's RAM. Now you have inside ram A. Please plug out RAM A and insert ram B and now start a test.

Comment: I mean that with only one new RAM in slot 1 the system loads until the windows screen and then gives bluescreen, it doesn't reboot automatically. I am also able to go in BIOS like this. But the diagnostics tool makes my pc reboot at 55%. It is the same for both RAMS. I attached an image to my original post.

Comment: May you give me Blue screen code ? It should look like this without   question mark 0x0000??????????

Comment: it is the irql_not_less_or_equal bluescreen.

Comment: Oke. Do you have one more hard drive ? If yes u can plug out actually hard drive with windows next  plug in another and install new Windows. It may solve problem. If yes again plug in you old hard drive and format

And you can look at this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560129(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I'll look for another drive. You perhaps have an idea how it is possible that when I re enter my normal RAMS my pc sometimes keeps hanging with black screen as well? Really strange, happened tonight after trying memtest and had to reboot like 20+ (cleared CMOS as well) times before it worked.

Comment: Do you have PC from shop ? I mean you have all components  for example Dell pc or Lenovo or something else ??? If you have Corporate computers they will have dedicated items like RAM, and you cant plug in another only dedicate. Or or... If you tell me "I have problem with PC" Under PC you mean Laptop.

Try to find another drive when you format and install you system Afresh and problem will still exist, we will try another solutions.

Comment: No, I assembled it myself some years ago. First time I encouter this kind of problems with something like RAM memory.

Comment: Ok, so try make format and we will see .

Comment: ouch! Just found at the website from memory itself that their rams are only compatible with the mentionned mb's and chipsets. Mine's not there...

Comment: So i think problem is a little bit resolved. You have wrong memory. I mean not compatible witch your mb. In this situation i think format will not resolve issued. I'm very sorry. You have to try change this ram  in online-shop where you bought it or try sell because it is little used ram . Good luck!